# Should I include my recent job for the background check or not?

Tags: new-job, job-change, job-offer, background-check

I left my last organization and joined a new company within the last two months. Now I have received another offer from a very reputed company. I have not informed them about my latest job and they only have information about my last company (which I left in March).

My questions are,

**Should I show my recent job & company information for the background check or not?**

**Will it create any issue in the background check?**

**Do companies find out about your job if you are not showing all of your job history to them?**

Answer (score 1):

You should complete your background forms honestly. A company performs a background check for various reasons. The two that really matter for this questions are the following:

- They want to see that what you told them that led to the job offer/hiring decision was accurate.
- That there are no unknown risks to hiring you and making you an employee in their environment (legal right to work, honest work ethic, criminal history etc.)

I find that honesty is always the best policy - They were aware of your circumstances when you applied for the job and those circumstances have changed. You should be honest and let them know that you are currently employed as if you do not include this information and they do find out, think what the consequences be? If a hiring manager was to find out in some way that you have not been completely honest there will be a bad image of you before you can even get your foot in the door.

@mhoran_psprep makes a valid point of dismissal down the line but to extend on this, what will that do to your future if you were to be dismissed due to a fail to declare your work history. Dependent on your location, you may be charged with fraud for your actions which will have a greater impact on your future then being honest with this potential employer.

Answer (score 0):

So your plan is to lie on the background forms. That doesn't sound like a good plan. Assume that they will find out that you lied. Now put themselves in their shoes. They will new have to determine if the missing information is the only thing you misled them about.

The background check could just be a records check or they could also interview friends and co-workers. Either way they may determine that you now work for a different company.

If you stopped working for a company in March you will have to note on the forms that your last day with the company was two months ago. They may ask you to also note periods when you were unemployed. If they check with the previous company expect that they will give the dates on employment.

Also note that just because you get past the background check, your aren't off the hook. You could get caught months later. If you are working at a place with at-will employmemnt laws this can be enough reason to dismiss you.